# JavaScript: check if an array is a subsequence of another array (write a faster naïve string search algo)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, search

```
[5, 4, 4, 6].indexOfArray([4, 6]) // 2
['foo', 'bar', 'baz'].indexOfArray(['foo', 'baz']) // -1
```

I came up with this:

```
Array.prototype.indexOfArray = function(array) {
    var m = array.length;
    var found;
    var index;
    var prevIndex = 0;
    while ((index = this.indexOf(array[0], prevIndex)) != -1) {
        found = true;
        for (var i = 1; i < m; i++) {
            if (this[index + i] != array[i]) {
                found = false;
            }
        }
        if (found) {
            return index;
        }
        prevIndex = index + 1
    }
    return index;
};
```

Later I have find [wikipedia calls it Naïve string search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm#Na.C3.AFve_string_search):

> In the normal case, we only have to look at one or two characters for each wrong position to see that it is a wrong position, so in the average case, this takes O(n + m) steps, where n is the length of the haystack and m is the length of the needle; but in the worst case, searching for a string like "aaaab" in a string like "aaaaaaaaab", it takes O(nm) steps.

Can someone write a faster indexOfArray method in JavaScript?

Comment: for starters you can check `if (array.length>this.length)return -1;`. Secondly, I don't see anything being much faster than js's native indexOf and continuing on from that index.

Comment: -1 for "Can someone write a faster indexOfArray method in JavaScript (no pseudocode, please)?"  Can you not read psuedocode or something? You might want to work on that.

Comment: Subset on title is missleading because it can also mean that the position of elements doesn't matter. But then, if the title contained the propper "substring" the question wouldn't exist in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

The algorithm you want is the KMP algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) used to find the starting index of a substring within a string -- you can do exactly the same thing for an array.

I couldn't find a javascript implementation, but here are implementations in other languages http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_implementation/String_searching/Knuth-Morris-Pratt_pattern_matcher -- it shouldn't be hard to convert one to js.

Comment: Although this is still O(nm) [worst-case] I believe.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW: I found this article a good read [Efficient substring searching](http://blog.phusion.nl/2010/12/06/efficient-substring-searching/) It discusses several variants of Boyer-Moore although it's not in JavaScript. The [Boyer-Moore-Horspool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer-Moore-Horspool_algorithm) variant (by Timo Raita’s -- see first link for link) was going to be my "suggestion" for a potential practical speed gain (does not reduce big-O though -- big-O is *upper limit only*!). Pay attention to the *Conclusion* at the bottom of the article and the benchmarks above.

I'm mainly trying to put up opposition for the Knuth-Morris-Pratt implementation ;-)