# How do I find a short subsequence of elements in an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a .js with a function that will check a long array if it contains a shorter one, also of a given sequence. I want the loop to check the first character of seqArray if it is the same as the first character of enzseqArray, then if the second of seqArray is the same as the second of enzseqArray and so on.

```
var i =0
var a=0
function f() {
if (seqArray[i]==enzseqArray[a]){a++}
else {a=0}
}
  for (i=0; i<=array.length; i++){
    for(a = 0; a<=enzymeHowManyBasesRecognized; f()){
    seqArrayLeftCopy.slice(0, counterNew)
    }
}
```

But the loop I've created seems to be an endless one and I cannot make out what's wrong with it.

Comment: longArr.toString().indexOf(shortArr.toString()) != -1 ?

Comment: Since you mention `character` - are your `arrays` actually strings? Then do `"abcd".includes("bc"); // true`

Comment: If you are not working on / don't want to convert to strings: Go with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980134/javascript-check-if-an-array-is-a-subsequence-of-another-array-write-a-faster

Comment: @le_m Thanks a buch, the trick with indexes worked after I adapted it to the program